# Difficulty in mentioning multiple calls in a single line of echo

Tags: bash, sh

The problem I have is with echo cannot echo e.g: "$prefix_$suffix". This is a assignment for a class in school if that changes things.

I've tried e.g "$prefix _$suffix" but that creates a space between the prefix and suffix

```
#!bin/bash

read -p "Username prefix: " prefix
read -p "Amount of users: " amount
read -p "Name of file to store, include extension (e.g test.txt): " filename
touch "$filename"
new="$amount"
suffix=0
state=true

while [ state=true ] ; do
    #in this function i reverse the user input amount of users so it appears as user 1,2,3 (and so on) in the first line of the text file that is also user input.
    if [ "$new" -ge 1 ] ; then
        newpass="$(gpg --gen-random --armor 1 12)"
        #reversing process, making the suffix start at 1 so user 1 gets assigned suffix 1 for the username and i decrease the "new" variable that gets set to "$amount" so the while loop isn't indefinite 
        new=`expr "$new" - 1`
        suffix=`expr "$suffix" + 1`

        echo -n "$prefix" >> "$filename"
        echo -n "_$suffix" >> "$filename"
        echo -n "  " >> "$filename"
        echo "$newpass" >> "$filename"
        echo -e >> "$filename"
    elif [ "$new" -eq 0 ] ; then
        break
    fi
done
```

a run of this bash results in 5 lines e.g:

re_1  UlrZW3jB5L9zt6Nf

and so on, depending how many users you choose at the input

however the next task is to create users with the username, in this example re_1 with the password: UlrZW3jB5L9zt6Nf. This is where the clunky echo stuff I've done doesn't work. I tried doing useradd -u "$prefix_$suffix" and "$prefix *$suffix" , none of these work since "$prefix*$suffix" is treated as one call instead of two and the "$prefix _$suffix" adds one space in between the prefix and suffix which is not acceptable.

Even if this looks very introverted to you, hence i added comments to make it understandable, help is very appreciated.

Feel free to ask question if you do not understand and want to help!

Comment: `[ state=true ]` is *always* true. It tests whether the string `state=true` is an empty string or not, and it's *always* a non-empty string. Maybe you meant `[ "$state" = true ]`? The whitespace isn't optional.

Comment: BTW, using `>>` over and over again is quite inefficient (every time you do that it re-opens your output file), and both `echo -e` and `echo -n` are bad form -- see [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which suggests using `printf` instead whenever you might otherwise reach for `-n` *or* use backslash-escape sequences. Anyhow, for the former, consider just `>"$filename"` at the end of the loop, opening the output file only once, truncating it when the loop starts, and then holding it open for the entire loop.

Comment: Also, shell-builtin math syntax like `foo=$(( foo + 1 ))` is **much** faster to run than `foo=$(expr foo + 1)`, since `expr` is a separate program that isn't part of the shell, so it needs to be started up, run, and then allowed to exit.

Comment: @Charles Duffy The state=true is just me being lazy, I run ubuntu on a virtual machine so I had to type it manually and simply forgot it, thanks for pointing out though!
I've only used >> since it works basically, I haven't dug into efficiency as I've just started out with bashing because the assignments just started to include bashing. 

I used expr because it was the first thing I found when googling and it worked.

Nonetheless, thanks a lot for the additional input, very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
echo "${prefix}_${suffix}"
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Is there a reason to use the {} for the prefix and suffix and not () , does it make a difference to which I use?

Comment: If teaching good practices, consider quoting -- `echo "${prefix}_${suffix}"`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: @Inoriha `${ }`, `$( )`, and `$(( ))` all have very different meanings -- the content is treated as a variable, command, and arithmetic expression respectively.